# Inconsistent list of hosts found by nmap pings from scan to scan - tcpdump shows ICMP echo replies did arrive

Tags: nmap

I'm running nmap periodically to monitor which hosts are in our server subnet:

```
rm list; for i in $(seq 1 254) ; do echo 10.10.10.$i >> list ; done
sudo nmap -oG - -PE -sn -iL list
```

Most of the time, it discovers 28 hosts, but sometimes less.

I've set up tshark (tcpdump) to capture all non-ssh traffic ([2scans.pcapng file](https://gist.github.com/pmorch/36663e39180a4857e85d895166ea25b7/raw/4e79b7b49ba02d87c654fa6facbb6f143715866d/2scans.pcapng)) and as far as I can tell, for some hosts, there is no difference in network traffic between when nmap reports a host as "Statups: Up" or not.

E.g. two subsequent runs of the nmap script above produced this output:

Scan 1:

```
# Nmap 6.47 scan initiated Fri Aug 10 11:12:57 2018 as: nmap -oG - -PE -sn -iL list
Host: 10.10.10.2 (access-switch01.capmon)   Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.3 (backnet-switch02.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.4 () Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.6 (c5-capmon.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.8 (blackboxserversensor.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.21 (overvaagning.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.50 (s-nas.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.63 (proxmox13.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.64 (proxmox14.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.66 (proxmox16.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.69 (proxmox01.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.71 (proxmox03.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.91 (proxmox11-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.92 (proxmox12-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.93 (proxmox13-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.95 (proxmox16-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.100 (nas.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.109 (nessus.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.248 (smsgw2.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.250 (asa.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.251 (pfsense.capmon) Status: Up
# Nmap done at Fri Aug 10 11:12:58 2018 -- 254 IP addresses (21 hosts up) scanned in 1.05 seconds
```

Scan 2:

```
# Nmap 6.47 scan initiated Fri Aug 10 11:13:08 2018 as: nmap -oG - -PE -sn -iL list
Host: 10.10.10.1 (capmon-backnet.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.2 (access-switch01.capmon)   Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.3 (backnet-switch02.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.4 () Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.6 (c5-capmon.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.8 (blackboxserversensor.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.21 (overvaagning.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.50 (s-nas.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.63 (proxmox13.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.64 (proxmox14.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.65 (proxmox15.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.66 (proxmox16.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.69 (proxmox01.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.71 (proxmox03.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.72 (proxmox04.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.73 (proxmox05.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.91 (proxmox11-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.92 (proxmox12-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.93 (proxmox13-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.94 (proxmox15-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.95 (proxmox16-imm.capmon)    Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.100 (nas.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.109 (nessus.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.122 ()   Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.248 (smsgw2.capmon)  Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.249 (smsgw.capmon)   Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.250 (asa.capmon) Status: Up
Host: 10.10.10.251 (pfsense.capmon) Status: Up
# Nmap done at Fri Aug 10 11:13:10 2018 -- 254 IP addresses (28 hosts up) scanned in 1.73 seconds
```

I've investigated the missing 10.10.10.1 and indeed, there is no ICMP Echo reply for it. But for e.g. 10.10.10.94, it seems the traffic to/from that host seems exactly the same for the two scans:

```
> tshark -ta -r 2scans.pcapng -Y 'ip.addr==10.10.10.94'
  633 11:12:58.475808 172.22.216.210 → 10.10.10.94  ICMP 42 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6527, seq=0/0, ttl=59
  639 11:12:58.476203  10.10.10.94 → 172.22.216.210 ICMP 60 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x6527, seq=0/0, ttl=63 (request in 633)
  752 11:12:58.589521 172.22.216.210 → 10.10.10.94  ICMP 42 Echo (ping) request  id=0x6823, seq=0/0, ttl=46
  761 11:12:58.589943  10.10.10.94 → 172.22.216.210 ICMP 60 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x6823, seq=0/0, ttl=63 (request in 752)
 1413 11:13:10.224663 172.22.216.210 → 10.10.10.94  ICMP 42 Echo (ping) request  id=0x379d, seq=0/0, ttl=45
 1416 11:13:10.225120  10.10.10.94 → 172.22.216.210 ICMP 60 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x379d, seq=0/0, ttl=63 (request in 1413)
 1443 11:13:10.324831 172.22.216.210 → 10.10.10.94  ICMP 42 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1e55, seq=0/0, ttl=58
 1446 11:13:10.325277  10.10.10.94 → 172.22.216.210 ICMP 60 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x1e55, seq=0/0, ttl=63 (request in 1443)
```

Can anybody explain why nmap didn't report 10.10.10.94 as up in the first scan  (packets 633-761)?

Comment: Not sure but from my point of view looks like there is a internal issue on nmap, my suggestion is to valgrind the command (valgrind ./nmap .....) and if you see reported issues from valgrind you should inform the nmap developers on the mailing list about it because could be a bug on it

Comment: [similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/956806/regular-nmap-scan-flaky-hosts-are-missing-sometimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my particular case, the problem was the `-PE` option to nmap. If I run nmap with the `-PE` option, it finds inconsistent results in about 1/3 of runs, whereas without `-PE` it is consistent over several 1000s of runs.

So we just stopped using `-PE`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an instance of [Nmap's ARP scan misses alive hosts in some cases · Issue #92 · nmap/nmap](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/92) - although I'm not certain. Several people have seen similar symptoms, but at the current state of this bug, nobody has a clue as to why.

Perhaps this was introduced between versions 4.11 and 4.53-1~bpo40+1 (debian version number). Perhaps not.